# TypeScript: Cannot use import statement outside a module (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig

I've been developing a package in node using typescript. When I install the package locally (i.e. providing the local path to the directory of the package, `$ npm install  ../my_package`) everything works fine.

But I've published the package in npm and now when I install the same package from npm it shows me the above-mentioned error:

```
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I could not find a solution to my problem anywhere. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me out here.

[Error Msg Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXCjV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the line below to your `package.json`.

```
"type": "module",
```

Comment: Thank you, Iman. But adding "type": "module", to my package.json doesn't actual solve my problem. Anyway, I found the solution myself. If anyone is having the same problem while developing in typescript here's how I solved it. Add "declaration": true, in tsconfig.json file (if you don't already have tsconfig.json file you can create one by $ tsc --init) also "outDir": "./dist", "rootDir": "./", . And in your package.json file add "types": "dist/index.d.ts", "main": "dist/index.js", .Compile the project by $ tsc . Ps.gitignore file add node_modules , /dist . Now publish it using $npm publish.

Comment: Post your answer in response to the question. It will help future people find the answer easier!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having the same problem while developing in typescript here's how I solved it.

If you don't already have tsconfig.json file you can create one by `$ tsc --init`.

Add the following to the tsconfig.json:

```json
"declaration": true,
"outDir": "./dist",
"rootDir": "./",
```

In your package.json file add

```json
"types": "dist/index.d.ts",
"main": "dist/index.js",
```

Compile the project with `$ tsc`.

Ps: in the `.gitignore` file add `node_modules` and `/dist`. Now publish it using `$npm publish`.